# bjam: Unable to load Boost.Build: could not find "boost-build.jam"

Tags: shell, boost, centos7

When running the `bjam` command I always come up with the following error.
I know I'm missing something like setting the env variables but not sure what should be the accurate value for those env variables. Your help would be highly appreciated.

```
Unable to load Boost.Build: could not find "boost-build.jam"
---------------------------------------------------------------
Attempted search from /tmp/libtorrent/libtorrent-rasterbar-1.1.4 up to the root
at /usr/share/boost-build
and in these directories from BOOST_BUILD_PATH and BOOST_ROOT: /tmp/libtorrent/libtorrent-rasterbar-1.1.4/build-aux/.
Please consult the documentation at 'http://www.boost.org'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build bjam, thats usually found under: `boost/boost_x_xx_x/tools/jam/src` but is built when you run the `boost/boost_X_XX_X/bootstrap.sh`.

Although this is built automatically you can force it to build by specifying on `boost/boost_X_XX_X/bootstrap.sh --with-bjam` the bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Arch Linux you can install the AUR [`boost-build`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/boost-build/) package.

Answer (score 0):

One way to allow b2 to find `boost-build.jam` is to define the environement variable `BOOST_BUILD_PATH` to point to the directory that contains it (where you did install or build b2).

There are other ways. More information [in the documentation](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#bbv2.overview.configuration).